# Where is the Thunderbolt Display's microphone located, and what are its specifications?

Tags: thunderbolt-display, microphone

There is a mesh above the camera on top of the display. Is that it?

I wonder if it's omni-directional or listening towards the front of the display.
I can't find any information about the location or specifications on apple.com or elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [iFixit teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Apple-Thunderbolt-Display-Teardown/6525/3) (see step 19) the microphone is indeed located above the camera behind the mesh. No word on the specs.

Comment: Just a hint: the quality of the mic is good, but the angle it records speach from a person sitting in fron of it is really bad. But if you manage to get something above the mic in a 45 degrees angle, the quality of your voice will increase by a large amount.

Answer (score 0):

The Microphone inside the Apple Monitor is designed to spy on employees who sit around the Monitor. There is software you can "get" that will discreetly listen and record unsuspecting employees talking around the monitor.

When the microphone is above the camera, it picks up noises that are within  a 360 degree angle... as opposed to 1 side (180 degrees) if it was located next to the camera.

For Privacy concerns, I placed a THICK piece of TAPE on both the Camera and Microphone of the Apple Monitor.

Hope this helps